# Selecting other vertices connected to a selected vertex of a mesh object

Tags: python, edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

As shown in the figure, I want to select the vertices that are connected to a selected vertice. In the left side of the figure, you can see a vertex of a cube is selected. My task is to select the circled vertices as shown in the right side of the figure.

I've tried "Ctrl+numpad+" (Grow selection), that gives me incorrect results as seen in the right figure, it selects some other vertices too (marked as question marks). Please advice me a way of doing the same and preferably in python script as I need to do this for a whole lot of objects.

[image: Vertex select and results of "Ctrl+numpad+"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is the 'select_more' operator under `bpy.ops.mesh`:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_more(use_face_step = False)
```

We're using the `use_face_step = False` parameter, to ensure it only selects linked vertices, not linked vertices via linked faces.

[image]

If you don't want to use operators, you can also use bmesh in a slightly longer script:

```
import bpy, bmesh

# Assuming active object in edit mode (for bmesh.from_edit_mesh)
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
   
# Get active vertex (assuming there is only 1 selected)
last = bm.select_history[-1] # history.active doesn't exist anymore...
                             # and last is a list, of one element

# Select all connected edges
for e in last.link_edges: e.select = True
    
bm.select_flush(True) # will update face selection

# this line is needed to close bmesh and see the result of the selection
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

Comment: Thank you again. I tried visiting all the edges one by one to check if a vertex is selected. If a vertex is selected, I selected the other vertex and vice versa. I'll compare the results from that with these ones. I used this script:
for k in range (0, len(obj.data.edges)):
    A = (bpy.data.meshes['mesh3606'].edges[k].vertices[0])
    B = (bpy.data.meshes['mesh3606'].edges[k].vertices[1])
    if obj.data.vertices[A].select == True:
        obj.data.vertices[B].select = True
    if obj.data.vertices[B].select == True:
        obj.data.vertices[A].select = True

Comment: bpy.ops.mesh.select_more(use_face_step = False) seems to be more correct that the visiting each edge (the method I mentioned previously). Thanks a lot. cheers!

Comment: No problem @Debaditya. The bmesh approach will also work, operators are usually considered to be slower than low level operations, which is why I specified the 2nd approach as well. In this case, however, if you're not worried about performance, the simplicity of the 1 line operator is a big advantage for code maintainability, in my opinion.

Comment: @TLousky why not  use `for e in v.link_edges: e.select = True` ? Also maybe `bm.select_history.active` could be used to get active vert.

Comment: @batFINGER, good suggestions. Will amend code.

Answer (score 4):

The Select More (and Select Less) includes an option in the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) for Face Step which is enabled by default.

[image: Face Step]

When enabled the section is grown (or shrunk) by *faces* rather than *edges*. Unchecking the Face Step checkbox changes the behavior to grow (or shrink) based on only edges.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply early reply. The method is correct, however, I was looking for an automatic way of doing it in Python script.